# Averaging for continuous data in flaot format

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am from engine testing field.
I want to average engine exhaust pressure value which is coming at 1Hz frequency continously.

I have to log this pressure value by doing its averaging by 10.

Someone please show me code for the same in vb langauge.

I tried  with the following code

```
Dim averageData (9) as double
Dim dummyVar as integer
Dim sum as integer
Dim number as integer
```

For number 1 to 10
From here I have to take data in array and take summation of the array elements and average it. After this I have to flush the array for new set. This script will run continuously until late testing is going on.

Comment: I'm downvoting because this question clearly lacks both research and effort. A simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Calculate+average+of+an+array+VB.NET) would've given you the answer you need, and there are many to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it.  It can be extended to a large number of samples, without increasing computation cost.

Here is C 'pseudo code' for this common algorithm.

```
typedef struct 
{
   int next;
   float sum;
   float readings[10];
} ravg_data;

float runningAverage(float value, ravg_data* data)
{
   data->sum += (value - data->readings[data->next]);
   data->readings[data->next] = value;
   if (++(data->next) >= 10)
     data->next = 0;
   return data->sum / 10;
}
```

For initializing/reset, simply use

```
memset(&data, 0, sizeof(ravg_data));
```

You will have to translate to VB, that should make up for you not posting code.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you write C++ code to answer a VB.NET question?

Comment: oops.  I thought I had tags on.

Comment: @Jack13 : Did you even try searching at Google? This kind of question has already been answered hundreds of times, and the very first one I get in the link I shared above is fairly similar to your question.

Comment: ... truth is, I haven't touched VB since the early 90's... ;)